# Lost my firefox icon

Tags: firefox, 20.04, icons

I accidentally messed up my menu, and firefox now no longer appears when I search for applications, and I don't have a way to mark it as 'favourite' when the application is running.

I've relegated to just start firefox with the terminal, but it's a bit of a pain because I have to keep it open, and shows a lot of error output.

Is there a way to tell apt, or dpkg or some other tool to restore the icon?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you did ("accidentally messed up my menu" is pretty vague), but I suspect that you if you reinstall Firefox, it should be re-added to your menu.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall firefox
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
sudo dpkg -P firefox
sudo apt install firefox
```

This should reinstall the `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop` file, hopefully re-adding it to your menu.

Comment: First one did not do the trick, but a bit scared to run the second and start over with my profile. Always a pain for a bit. I think I'm just gonna live with this for a little bit..

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this with dconf, procedure is almost the same but this is a little easier.
I think you have to at least one thing added to your favorites before they will show up here. I don't use the default desktop (i hate it), I use flashback, so I am not sure if that behavior is the same... Flashback already had default favorites when I did these commands..

list your favorites:

`gsettings list-recursively | grep favorite`

org.gnome.shell favorite-apps ['ubiquity.desktop', 'thunderbird.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'rhythmbox.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'snap-store_ubuntu-software.desktop', 'yelp.desktop']

that's the line you want... if you don't see an "org.gnome.shell favorite-apps" line, add a favorite and try it again.

firefox.desktop should still actually be on your machine at /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop

So all you have to do is add it to the end of your favorites line with gsettings, with the entire line **"[INSIDE QUOTES]"**.

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps "['ubiquity.desktop', 'thunderbird.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'rhythmbox.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'snap-store_ubuntu-software.desktop', 'yelp.desktop','firefox.desktop']"`

It appears on my machine immediately..... and ones that I leave off of the line, it removes them from the desktop immediately... So make sure to copy your old line correctly... maybe copy it to a text file while you are working with it for safe keeping.

If you really messed up and somehow deleted your /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop file. You will have to make another one. This worked for me:

create a file with a text editor, I used vi.

`sudo vi /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop`  *...i actually called it poop.desktop, you can actually call it what you want and use that name in the gsettings assignment...which is good to know for creating future launchers*

paste in the text:

[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Mozilla Firefox
GenericName=Web Browser
Comment=Browse the Web
Exec=firefox %u
Icon=firefox.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml;text/mml;
StartupNotify=True

save it

Comment: I did have this file, but using your version did not fix it. I also reset my favourites with your exact line, also no dice.. firefox icon didn't come back in my menu. Very weird!

Comment: well, hopefully you didn't use my "exact" line? that was from my computer... you need to show your line with the first command and take that line and add firefox.desktop to it.... can you post your screenshot? of your sequence?

Comment: @Evert you didnt happen to run the gsettings command as sudo or root did you? you do that part as the user.

Comment: Did not. Pretty strange! Considering just making a new user profile =)

Comment: that is odd, can you cut and paste your output from `gsettings list-recursively | grep favorite`

Comment: `org.gnome.shell favorite-apps ['thunderbird.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'rhythmbox.desktop']` (after cleaning up some of your entries)

Comment: here are the dconf instructions: `dconf read /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps` and then you add firefox.desktop to that output and you write it back to the dconf db with `dconf write /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps "['ubiquity.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'rhythmbox.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'snap-store_ubuntu-software.desktop', 'yelp.desktop', 'firefox.desktop']"` ...I used the gsettings answer first because that way you can easily grep what you are looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110790/discussion-between-wu-tang-and-evert).

Comment: @Evert you should post what you found wrong with your system as your answer, someone else may benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Download an Icon.
Then,go to /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop

`nano /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop`

and search for Icon and edit it as,

Icon=/path/to/icon